# How do I set up my iptables to allow web traffic to my Spring Boot application?

Tags: linux, spring-boot, vps, iptables

I am trying to host my Spring Boot application on Arvixe's VPS Lite. No CPanel, just command line.

When I spin up my Spring Boot app and navigate to the server's IP address, I see the ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error.

Here is my iptables configuration. I followed the steps found here http://crm.vpscheap.net/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=29

```
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --sport 80 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --sport 443 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --sport 22 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --sport 22 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --sport 443 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --sport 80 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p udp -o eth0 --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -i eth0 --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m limit --limit 25/minute --limit-burst 100 -j ACCEPT

-A INPUT -j DROP
COMMIT
```

Here are the policies that the above creates

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:http state NEW,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:https state NEW,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ssh state NEW,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp spt:ssh state ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp spt:https state ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp spt:http state ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp spt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:http limit: avg 25/min burst 100
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp spt:http state ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp spt:https state ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp spt:ssh state ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ssh state NEW,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:https state NEW,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:http state NEW,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:domain
```

Answer (score 0):

In your iptables config you are opening up ports 80 and 443 but spring-boot applications are starting on port 8080 per default. So you have two options:

1. Start the app listing on port 80 by adding `--server.port=80` to the start up params or set `server.port=80` in the application.properties. This will work but you'll have to start the app as `root` since it trying to bind to a well known port. I wouldn't recommend this.
2. Use iptables to redirect the external port 80 to be forwarded internally to port 8080 by adding a line like the following to your iptables config

   ```
   iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
   ```